# Cron runs command but it has no effect. How to fix?

Tags: cron, find

I have a storage directory on my apache server and I need to remove all files and folders in it every 6 hours.

To achieve that I added next line to crontab file:

```
* */6   * * * root   find ~/project/storage -type f -mmin +720 -delete
```

I ran command manually - it works.

Cron also works and I get next line in logs:

```
CRON[31641]: (root) CMD (find ~/project/storage -type f -mmin +720 -delete)
```

But in reality, it does not delete files and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you expect the "~"  in `~/project/storage` does? 1 thing I can guarantee you is that it will NOT expand to /home/$USER/.

Solution: always use explicit (/absolute) paths when you use any of the crons.

And regarding your method a tip: I would never do it like this. If I was you I would create a compressed tar file with a timestamp first, then remove the files and store the compressed tar file in a different directory and remove those tar files after a grace period (like a week or a month or even after a year). I can not tell you how often that method saved my skin in the past 25 years. If even to solve a question from a client asking what happened with some action they did.

Comment: Thank you, i will try to change path. I have no opportunity to store something more than several hours. My server has 20 GB free space, and files that I store are used by users once, but weights from 300 Mb to 3 Gb